# How to save image in android gallery

Tags: android, android-imageview

I try to save the image into WathsappIMG but when I go to image gallery android I don't see the image and the image there into the directory can be seen from ES File Explorer

```
OutputStream output;
       // Find the SD Card path
        File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

      // Create a new folder in SD Card
     File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
              + "/WhatSappIMG/");
        dir.mkdirs(); 

     // Retrieve the image from the res folder
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) principal.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap1 = drawable.getBitmap();

        // Create a name for the saved image
        File file = new File(dir, "Wallpaper.jpg" );

        try {

            output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
            bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
            output.flush();
            output.close();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Does the folder have a file called ".nomedia"? Check with ES File Explorer, you may need to check hidden files, enable that from the ES File Explorer slide menu.

Comment: No man no have .nomedia

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**the gallery don't displaying (necessarily) files from external storage.**

this is a common mistake.

the gallery displays images stored on the [media store provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html)

you can use this method to store image file on media store provider:

```
public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Comment: I newbie on  android how implements your code in my code :/ I need that save image in the file /WhatSappIMG/ :/

Comment: add this method to your code, and add this line after the "output.close();": addImageToGallery(file.getAbsolutePath(), YourActivity.this);

Comment: the code you provided implemented inside Activity class?  if so then YourActivity is the Name of your activity

Comment: if you asked that - then you probably newbie not only on android, but also in java

Comment: I can chat with you on skype o another chat ? xD

Comment: hmm... yes!   but in 10 minutes from now.  I'm going for 10 minutes now.  my skype id is "talkanel"

Comment: This is the correct answer; trying to use the other answers here [results in headache if you're trying to add a PNG file.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358576/when-saving-bitmap-to-disk-solid-paths-show-artifacts)

Comment: FYI - I thought I'd be creative and try sending the byte[] of the image to MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA instead of the path. DO NOT do this. It corrupted my gallery app and I had to reset the phone.

Comment: How do I save it using custom filename?

Answer (score 12):

here is what you should enter, when you're about to save the picture in the Gallery

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);
```

That code will add the image at the end of the Gallery. so please, check your Gallery picture, to be sure

Comment: Can I determine the album's name?

Comment: @DanielReyhanian Path is: sdcard=>Pictures

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this:

`MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);`

Fill in your details for yourBitmap, yourTitle, and yourDescription, or just leave it as `""`.

Comment: This work but save the image in when imagen of camera i need that save imagen in my directory :/

Answer (score 2):

For Xamarin fellows:

```cs
public static void SaveToTheGalley(this string filePath, Context context)
{
    var values = new ContentValues();
    values.Put(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.DateTaken, Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis());
    values.Put(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.MimeType, "image/jpeg");
    values.Put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data, filePath);
    context.ContentResolver.Insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, values);
}
```

And don't forget about `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: I feel like your answer doesn't get enough appreciation. Thanks a lot, you just saved for me tons of hours and my code works perfectly. Also, it's nice to see that people also do care about the ones who use Xamarin.

Answer (score 2):

As

```
MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data
```

and

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage
```

is deprecated now,
here is how I did it using bitmap

```
fun addImageToGallery(
    fileName: String,
    context: Context,
    bitmap: Bitmap
) {

        val values = ContentValues()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
        }
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.TITLE, fileName)

        val uri: Uri? = context.contentResolver.insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            values
        )
        uri?.let {
            context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)?.let { stream ->
                val oStream =
                    BufferedOutputStream(stream)
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, oStream)
                oStream.close()
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change this piece of code-

```
try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
        bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap1,
        "Wallpaper.jpg", null);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This compresses the image and the size of the image is changed then.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly refer this code worked for me:

```
public static boolean saveImageToGallery(Context context, Bitmap bmp) {
    // First save the picture
    String storePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "dearxy";
    File appDir = new File(storePath);
    if (!appDir.exists()) {
        appDir.mkdir();
    }
    String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(appDir, fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        //Compress and save pictures by io stream
        boolean isSuccess = bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        //Insert files into the system Gallery
        //MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), fileName, null);

        //Update the database by sending broadcast notifications after saving pictures
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri));
        if (isSuccess) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to make your image visible in the gallery.

```
    public void saveImageToGallery(Context context, Uri path) {
        // Create image from the Uri for storing it in the preferred location
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        try {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
                bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, path);
            } else {
                ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(contentResolver, path);
                bmp = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        // Store image to internal storage/ImagePicker directory
        String storePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "ImagePicker";
        File appDir = new File(storePath);
        if (!appDir.exists()) {
            appDir.mkdir();
        }
        String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(appDir, fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            boolean isSuccess = bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            
            // Broadcast the image & make it visible in the gallery
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri));
            if (isSuccess) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "File saved to gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```