# How do I browse the DIRECTORY_PICTURES folder on my Android device?

Tags: android

When I save images to the Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES directory they do not show up in the Photos app. Therefore I assume the Photos app only shows the contents of Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM.

With what standard app can I browse DIRECTORY_PICTURES?

or has DCIM become the de-facto pictures directory?

(See Docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)

Comment: What is your question? Are you trying to browse it within your app? Or are you looking for an app to browse it for you? Or a library?

Comment: It is accessed through the environment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_PICTURES

Comment: @ChrisS I was looking for a standard app. I said so in my OP. (The app I was looking for is indeed Photos.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was spurred by an assumption that the Photos app only showed *photos* (ie DCIM). But it seems that the name is a misnomer and that [on Android the Photos app is now the universal image gallery](http://www.androidcentral.com/where-did-gallery-go-after-lollipop-update).

I asked this question because images I was saving to DIRECTORY_PICTURES were not showing up in the Photos app. I think its because I was not properly adding them to the MediaStore database.

This was the solution: [how to save images in android gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859584/how-save-image-in-android-gallery).

Answer (score 0):

Every android device has a default photo viewer. Let the user choose:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```